# Prefer appended optional regex group over dot metacharacter

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a regular expression that matches everything before an optional group, however I need the optional group to be preferred over the `.` metacharacter.

As long as the group isn't optional, everything works as I expect it:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.+)(\d+)','asdasd2').groups()
('asdasd', '2')
```

However, when marking it as optional, the result doesn't match my needs anymore:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.+)(\d+)?','asdasd2').groups()
('asdasd2', None)
```

Using the non-greedy modifier `?` on the `.` makes it even worse:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.+?)(\d+)?','asdasd2').groups()
('a', None)
```

This is an abstraction of a more complex regex I have in my actual code, where the optional group is pretty complex by itself, so using `[^somecharacter]` instead of `.` is not an option. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you are looking for, assuming you always want two groups returned from your search:

```
>>> re.match(r'(.+(?=\d+)|.+)(\d+)?', 'asdasd2').groups()
('asdasd', '2')
>>> re.match(r'(.+(?=\d+)|.+)(\d+)?', 'asdasd').groups()
('asdasd', None)
```

The first group `(.+(?=\d+)|.+)` looks for either a group of characters followed by a digit (but not including the digit) or just a group of characters (implicitly not followed by a digit, since that case would have been caught by `(.+(?=\d+)`). The second group `(\d+)?` looks for 0 or 1 occurrences of a group of digits.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an `|` operator for the expression with and without the optional group.

`(?:(.+)(\d+)|(.+))`

```
>>> re.match(r'(?:(.+)(\d+)|(.+))','asdasd2').groups()
('asdasd', '2', None)
>>> re.match(r'(?:(.+)(\d+)|(.+))','asdasd').groups()
(None, None, 'asdasd')
>>> re.match(r'(?:(.+)(\d+)|(.+))','asdasd23abc3').groups()
('asdasd23abc', '3', None)
```